# How do I prevent foreach statement from removing my decimals?

Tags: php, foreach, decimal

A project I'm working on has me at my wit's end. I'm new to coding in PHP which I'm sure will be fairly obvious from my question. I have an XML file with multiple item elements that I'm listing in a table. At the end of the table I have another row that displays the total weight. If all of the weights are whole numbers, it works fine. The problem I'm running into is that if any of my item weights have decimals in them, they seem to disappear during the calculation. Here is an example of the foreach statement I'm running.

```
foreach ($xml->items->item as $item) {
$ItemWeight = (($item->weight) * ($item->quantity)) + $ItemWeight;
}
```

And an excerpt from the XML document.

```
<items>
    <item>
        <name>Sleeping Bag</name>
        <weight>5</weight>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Clothes</name>
        <weight>2.5</weight>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Socks</name>
        <weight>.5</weight>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>MRE</name>
        <weight>1</weight>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
    </item>
</item>
```

In my example `Clothes` would be calculated at a total weight of 10 instead of 12.5 and `Socks` would disappear entirely. `$ItemWeight` output would be 20 instead of 27.5.

Comment: I apologize if I'm being an idiot, but what do you mean by input data?

Comment: What is value of `$item->weight`?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to debug the code by checking the values of the individual node. You can try the following piece of code that gets the correct value 27.5.

Here I have converted the xml to an array which should not be required. This was just a quick and dirty solution. You can see that there's not problem with the foreach. I believe the values that you are passing are wrong.

```
  $xmlstring = '
<items>
    <item>
        <name>Sleeping Bag</name>
        <weight>5</weight>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Clothes</name>
        <weight>2.5</weight>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>Socks</name>
        <weight>.5</weight>
        <quantity>10</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>MRE</name>
        <weight>1</weight>
        <quantity>5</quantity>
    </item>
</items>';


$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$items = json_decode($json,FALSE);
$ItemWeight=0;
foreach ($items->item as $item) {
$ItemWeight = (($item->weight) * ($item->quantity)) + $ItemWeight;
echo $ItemWeight."\n";
}
```

Comment: So your answer got me digging, and I think I've realized the root problem. When I load the XML it loads it as a string, and then when I start doing calculations with it, it converts it into an integer and drops the decimal. So I guess the new question, is how do I load an XML document as something other than a string?

Comment: The problem is not that you are loading the XML into a string. The problem is that you are not converting the string into a desired type. You should extract the desired type using floatval() function, which will preserve the fraction that you are losing out due to round off.

Answer (score 0):

Try using floatval()

So your foreach loop would look like this:

```
   foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
   $weight = floatval(($item->weight));
   $quantity = floatval(($item->quantity));
   $ItemWeight = ($weight * $quantity);
   echo $ItemWeight."\n";
```